# What are the features of the BindAsync function?

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, bind

**What are the features of the `BindAsync` function?**

I have an example method that uses this command after a get all.

```
public async Task<Either<Exception, List<Clients>>> BuscarClientes()
{
    return await GetAllByAsync(x => true)
                    .BindAsync(clients => 
        {
            clients = clients.Where(x => x.active == "S")
                             .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            return clients
        }
}
```

this method creates a rule that returns a list of active clients sorted by name.

It returns this list from the `GetAllByAsync` method:

```
public virtual async Task<Either<Exception, IEnumerable<TEntity>>> GetAllByAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> parameter)
{
    try
    {
        return Right<Exception, Option<TEntity>>(await DBEntity.Where(parameter).ToListAsync());
    }
    catch
    {
        return ex;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what this `BindAsync` method is for, how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume the `BindAsync` extension function comes from [`Monacs`](https://github.com/MonacsLib/Monacs/blob/master/Monacs.Core/Result.Extensions.Async.cs) functional extensions for C#.

The purpose of the method, as described in docs is

```
/// <summary>
/// Transforms the <paramref name="result"/> into another <see cref="Result{T}"/> using the <paramref name="binder"/> function.
/// If the input result is Ok, returns the value of the binder call (which is <see cref="Result{T}"/> of <typeparamref name="TOut"/>).
/// Otherwise returns Error case of the Result of <typeparamref name="TOut"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TIn">Type of the value in the input result.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TOut">Type of the value in the returned result.</typeparam>
/// <param name="result">The result to bind with.</param>
/// <param name="binder">Function called with the input result value if it's Ok case.</param>
public static async Task<Result<TOut>> BindAsync<TIn, TOut>(this Result<TIn> result, Func<TIn, Task<Result<TOut>>> binder) =>
    result.IsOk ? await binder(result.Value) : Error<TOut>(result.Error);
```

Meaning it takes the result of async operation passed in and exposes it, wrapped in `Task`, after applying function passed in as `binder`.